# Table of results of metrics does not appears well, cell not closed and lines divides horizontally and vertically

Tags: tables, rules

I ma trying to write a table to put my results on. But I am getting this error. The lines are not fulling designed.

```
           
  

\begin{table}
\centering
   \begin{tabular}{|c|S|S|S|S|S|S|S|S|}           \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{TAD}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Base cased}    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Base uncased} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{IxBert} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Large base} \\   \cline{8-9}
  & {Micro-P.} & {Macro-P.} & {Micro-P.}  & {Macro-P.}  & {Micro-P.} & {Macro-P.} & {Micro-P.}  & {Macro-P.}            \\   \hline 

Retro & & & &  & & & &  &   \\    \cline{2-9}
SubsSyn & & & &  & & & &  &   \\     \cline{2-9}
InjM & & & &  & & & &  &   \\     \cline{2-9}
InjL& & & &  & & & &  &   \\     \cline{2-9}
& & & &  & & & &  &   \\     \hline
           
           
           
         
%\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Average}   & 76.42 & 66.52 &69.8 & 56.54 \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{An important table}
\end{table}
```

The result looks like this. How can I improved so that all the lines are fully closed and the table appear at the center of the page (A4)[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using more `&`s than necessary. It helps the checking by lining them up.

[image: b]

The table is to wide for the allocated text width. It will require a redesign, which will depend on your data.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[left=1.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{TAD}    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Basecased} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Baseuncased}   &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{IxBert}    &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Largebase}\\\cline{2-9}
                            &{Micro-P.} &{Macro-P.}         &{Micro-P.} &{Macro-P.}             &{Micro-P.} &{Macro-P.}         &{Micro-P.} &{Macro-P.}\\ \hline
    Retro                   &           &                   &           &                       &           &                   &           &\\ \cline{2-9}%<<<<<<<<<<<<
    SubsSyn                 &           &                   &           &                       &           &                   &           &\\ \cline{2-9}
    InjM                    &           &                   &           &                       &           &                   &           &\\ \cline{2-9}
    InjL                    &           &                   &           &                       &           &                   &           &\\\cline{2-9}
                            &           &                   &           &                       &           &                   &           &\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{An important table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Number of ampersands had to for one less than is number of colummns in table. This in your case means, that for 9 columns in each row in table had to have 8 ampersands (but you have 9).

For your table I would use `tabularray` package with `siunitx` library. However due to lack of information about your document, there can be problem how to fit your table on page:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{1-3,Z}, hline{4-Y}={2-Z}{solid},
             vlines,
             colspec={c *{8}{S[table-format=3.3]} },
             rowsep =3pt,
             }   
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    TAD
         &  \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Basecased}}}
            &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Baseuncased}}}
                    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{IxBert}}}
                            &       
                                &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {{{Largebase}}}     \\
        &{{{Micro-P.}}} &{{{Macro-P.}}} &{{{Micro-P.}}} &{{{Macro-P.}}}
        &{{{Micro-P.}}} &{{{Macro-P.}}} &{{{Micro-P.}}} &{{{Macro-P.}}}    \\
Retro   &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\ 
SubsSyn &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
InjM    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
InjL    &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
        &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &           \\
Average & 76.42 & 66.52 & 69.8  & 56.54 &       &       &       &           \\
    \end{tblr}
\caption{An important table}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)